# juju destroy-service do not remove failed services

Tags: juju

I have deployed a service through JUJU in my local environment but it got failed due to a bug in my charm. Now I wanted to remove this failed service from the environment. I executed three commands in following hierarchy:

```
juju destroy-service servicename
juju destroy-unit servicename/0
juju destroy-machine machinename
```

The first 2 commands executed without any error but third command gave me an error like (the error is not exact as i lost that console):

`Failed to remove machine "machinename". It is associated with unit "servicename/0".`

Now I can not remove this machine through JUJU. Also the related service is still being shown on JUJU UI and status command output.

Is the above hierarchy good?
Is there any work around to remove this service + associated machine through JUJU. If I remove this machine through lxc-destroy command, it leaves the juju in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to destroy the machine gracefully until the services and units associated with that machine have been removed. Running `juju destroy-service serviceName` will destroy all of the associated units eventually but will leave the machines around (by default). You can then follow-up with `juju destroy-machine machineName` which will destroy the machine.

If you are not able to destroy the machine using `destroy-machine` you can append `--force` to the end to force it to destroy. This basically simply sends the terminate command to the provider so only use as a last resort: `juju destroy-machine machineName --force`.

To find out of the unit is still associated to the machine you can run `juju status` in the console and it should only list empty machines.

Note: You will probably have better luck getting juju related questions answered if you ask on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: The destroy-service and destroy-machine commands are not working as intended. You can see I am already executing these commands. Though your suggestion about http://askubuntu.com/ is good. Thanks.

Comment: @Kashif I added some information about using --force with destroy-machine. This should get you back on track.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this parameter. I destroyed that environment where i was facing this issue as i have to fix some stuff as soon as possible. I will test this parameter if I encounter that issue again. Thanks again @Hatch.